# Jasper iReport weird space between Static Text and Text Field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper/iReport with Static Text and a Text Field directly behind it as such:
[image]

As you can see there is almost no extra space between the two fields. But when I render it, it shows up like this:

[image]

Any idea why?

Jrxml Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fcf485a8-4a9b-49b5-ba23-15b22808d171">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="682"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="testfield" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="107" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="49" width="224" height="15" uuid="d706eb33-a1da-4ec2-b774-f27d6ea50b72"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Please Note: In order to qualify for the Earlybird Discounts]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="224" y="49" width="59" height="15" uuid="a559bcca-c8b7-4a12-a45a-ee7a6677cccf"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{testfield} != null) ? $F{testfield} : "This is text field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I noticed that when I preview in iReport it shows fine, but when you open in Adobe Reader, it has extra space.

Comment: Thing that first comes to my mind is to add border on both elements and see whats going on

Comment: It depends on alignment, font size and so on. You should post small *jrxml* to reproduce the isssue

Comment: jrxml sample added

Answer (score 0):

You could put both texts into a Text Field together like:
"RECEIVED BEFORE OR ON " + $P{invoiceDTO}

If thats not feasable set "Stretch type: No Stretch" in Appearance.